# Trying to Auto Fill to last row of data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill a column with `VLOOKUP`. I want to fill the range from the current cell down to the last row with data. I have looked at the questions here and I have looked at other examples and it should work but all it is doing is stopping at the first blank cell. I am trying to take the vlookup in `D3` and autofill it down to the last row with data. Here is my code so far.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],Messages.csv!C1:C18,15,FALSE)"
Range("D3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D" & lastRow)
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need the `FillDown` method?

Comment: "down to the last row with data" In what column are the data? In `D` they can't be, since there shall be the formulas. But your `Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` looks for the last filled cell in column `D`.  According to your formula maybe `lastRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid methods like `.Select` and `.ActiveCell`. Try this instead:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D3:D" & lastRow) = "=VLOOKUP(RC[2],Messages.csv!C1:C18,15,FALSE)"
```

If `lastRow` doesn't represent the last row you are looking for, change it to:

```
lastRow = Range("<column with the last row you are looking for>" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

(Obviously not that text, I think it's probably column `C` or `F`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (assuming the ActiveCell is D3):

```
Range(Range("D3"),Range("D" & lastrow)).FillDown
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from explaining how `FillDown` differs from `AutoFill` and why you think it's preferable.